# Using MySQL or NoSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, nosql

I'm going to start a large web application, the app will be powered by PHP (YiiFramework), and I wish to build before launching the app a strong and high scalability architecture able to handle huge amount of traffic.

The app SQL queries approx (80% read, 20% between update & insert), I have actually 15 tables in the database, and many mediumtext columns, it will be many queries searching by text eg(WHERE `foo` LIKE '%VARS%')

I will use PHP APC to boost performance, as well starting with a Memcached server, and work with Nginx as reserve proxy.

for Database:
can a NoSQL database replace RDBMS like MySQL?

Is NoSQL database is more efficient than MySQL?

What is the best NoSQL database solution for my case (80% read, 20% between update & insert), and why?

Comment: hire a db professional to look at it, there are way to many factors to give a meaningful answer here.

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but you should add varnish as a caching proxy to your list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LIKE '%term%' will not scale.  The queries will always be O(N) based on the number of rows in the table.  As you add rows, the query will get slower.

You will want to use text indexes.  Look at using Sphinx or SOLR.

[Sphinx full text search](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
[SOLR full text search](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: Another alternative -although not a very mature project- is ElasticSearch. Great for big databases with a big amount of text. As Justin Swanhart says, you'll get in trouble with RDBMS if there are big tables and you get a lot of 'LIKE "%term"' type queries.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of questions.

A nosql DB can potentially replace a RDBMS. It depends on your infrastructure and organization needs. But technically its no problem. I don't know a lot of queries you couldn't do with map reduce you can do with sql.

If it is more efficient depends on your needs. If you are using a lot of text searches try an index like lucene (solr) to boost performance in both cases. But there are also solutions with nosql and indices. So an experienced programmer with rdbms can definitely outboost an unexperienced nosql programmer and vice versa.

I have some experience with couchdb and it is fast for my application. But it depends. And most stable nosql database are fast, also rdbms are fast. It depends so much on the exact queries and setup.